# Syntax Files in Vim - Vim only looks at syntax.vim

Tags: vim

So, I have a bunch of .vim syntax files for different languages inside my $VIMRUNTIME/syntax folder.

How do I make vim use these syntax files ? Currently, vim only looks for syntax.vim (it complains if syntax.vim is not there) and so is there something I should include in syntax.vim for vim to recognize the other language syntax files ?

P.S:

I do have `syntax on` in my .vimrc

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do to is to add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
```

It turns filetype detection and syntax highlighting *on* so this command should open a syntax highlighted `file.py`:

```
$ vim file.py
```

Comment: Hmm.. I do have `syntax on` in my vimrc. But I get the same result - vim complains about the missing syntax.vim file.

Comment: Did you do anything in `$VIMRUNTIME`? What is the path of your `vimrc`?

Comment: So my $VIMRUNTIME="/opt/<some folder>/share/vim". And my vimrc is in ~

Answer (score 0):

With `:syntax on`, Vim should successfully load a syntax script from e.g. `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/java.vim` when you do `:set syntax=java`.

You can verify with the `:scriptnames` output that this indeed is loaded. Also, you can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for what places Vim has searched.